updating Ubuntu server from 20.04 LTS to 22.04 LTS not 24.04 LTS
how can I update the server to a previous LTS and not the very latest one? I need to update Ubuntu server from 20.04 LTS to 22.04 LTS not 24.04 LTS. Can any one help me in this?
Thank you in advance.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Does this answer your question? Can I skip over releases when upgrading?

Does this answer your question? How do I upgrade to a newer version of Ubuntu?

Sorry, I don't see a problem.
Ubuntu 20.04 LTS has only a single upgrade option, to the NEXT LTS release which is Ubuntu 22.04 LTS.
If you want to go to 24.04 LTS, you need to upgrade yourself to 22.04 LTS, and even then wait, as upgrades to 24.04 LTS are currently not even open (it's available for new installs only currently, however will open for upgrades from 23.10 soon, and upgrades from 22.04 AFTER the release of Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS which is still some months in the future).
You seem to be worried about an upgrade that currently isn't even possible, and even when possible, won't be available to you [currently] as your system [release] is too old (thus need to perform multiple release-upgrades to get there).
Instructions on upgrading to 22.04 LTS can be seen at
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/JammyUpgrades

Technically a 20.04 system would have also upgraded to groovy or 20.10 long ago (ie. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/GroovyUpgrades) but all non-LTS upgrade options are history for 20.04 now as they disappear when the release where release-upgrade was possible to goes EOL, and thus only a release-upgrade to 22.04 is available.
