20.04lts to 24.04lts upgrade possible?
do I have to upgrade from 20.04lts to 22.04lts, then upgrade from 22.04lts to 24.04lts - or can it be done directly from 20.04lts to 24.04lts?

Ubuntu does not allow jumping LTS versions. So, no. You may back up your data and install 24.04 if you don't want to go through the intermediate step of upgrading to 22.04.

You may find this answer https://askubuntu.com/questions/1512439/updating-ubuntu-server-from-20-04-lts-to-22-04-lts-not-24-04-lts/1512487#1512487 helpful   (from a user worried their 20.04 upgrade would go to 24.04, which they didn't want)

You can non-destructively re-install a later release for some products (some installers), but that is not intended for server use, and you didn't mention product.

Thanks user68186, I'll go ahead and upgrade to 22.04lts, then wait a week to upgrade to 24.04lts,
